# CommandButton not invoked

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces

My `commandButton` is not invoked when I set the value of an `inputText`, via ajax.

This is a portion of my code :

```
<h:form>
<tr>
<td><p:outputLabel>Numéro Inscription</p:outputLabel></td>  
<td><h:inputText class="span1" id="numIns" value="#{orientationMB.numins}">
    <p:ajax update="nom prenom choix1 choix2 choix3" />
</h:inputText>
</td>
<td><p:outputLabel>Nom</p:outputLabel></td>
<td><h:inputText disabled="true" id="nom" value{orientationMB.eleve.nom}"/></td>
<td><p:outputLabel>Prénom</p:outputLabel></td>
<td><h:inputText disabled="true" id="prenom"  value="#k{orientationMB.eleve.prenom}"/></td>                         
</tr>
<p:commandButton value="Créer" actionListener="#{orientationMB.ajouterOrientation}" /><br/><br/><h:form>
```

The backup method of the bean is comprised only of a `system.out("------")`

Comment: Check all that is in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked

Comment: and `tr` directly within an `h:form`?

Comment: That `p:ajax` under `h:inputText` doesn't make sense. You probably wanted to add the `update` attribute on your `p:commandButton` instead.